# Highcharts white space between grouped bars

Tags: highcharts, whitespace, space

I'd like to know if this is possible?

I want to group certain bars by adding white spacers. In my Google Spreadsheet I add an empty row, but then Highcharts renders a row number as category. The image explains my issue.

![screenshot]http://www.exelmans.be/forums/screenshot-highcharts.png

Comment: Would be better if you post your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can set for empty categories an empty string: `categories: ['a','b','c','', 'e','f','g', '','i','j','k']`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/97/